# Difference between accent Color and the main color in flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design

I am an absolute beginner in Flutter Development. I have tried
different combinations and searched a lot on web but due to the unawareness of Flutter norms
I am unable to understand the differences even from my implementations.

I would request you to please clear the differences including their best
uses.

Comment: I think this more about Material design than Flutter. Those 2 links should help you undestand what primary, secondary, acceent colors mean and what is their purpose: https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html#sheets-surfaces https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYkz0Ueg0L4

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Primary color

> A primary color is the color displayed most frequently across your app’s screens and components.If you don’t have a secondary color, your primary color can also be used to accent elements.

[image]

---

## Secondary color

Accent color is also known as Secondary color.

> A secondary color provides more ways to accent and distinguish your product. Having a secondary color is optional, and should be applied sparingly to accent select parts of your UI.

Secondary colors are best for:

- Floating action buttons
- Selection controls, like sliders and switches
- Highlighting selected text
- Progress bars
- Links and headlines

To read more head over to [official link](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation)

[image]

---

### How to declare theme in Flutter App?

```
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      // Define the default brightness and colors.
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
      accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
    ),
```

Answer (score 7):

A primary color is the color displayed most frequently across your app’s screens and components.

An Accent color(also known as secondary color) provides more ways to accent and distinguish your product.
Accent colors are generally applied to:
-Floating action buttons
-Selection controls, like sliders and switches
-Highlighting selected text
-Progress bars
-Links and headlines

Also, you should read out the [ThemeData Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html) To understand how themes, colors and styles works and applies to the different widgets and pages in the flutter.

Theme Data has lots of properties like primarySwatch, accentColor, primaryColor, buttonColor and what not? You can checkout each one to briefly understand the material structure applies to the app themes and styles in the flutter.